# How to read response of a JIRA REST API

Tags: bash, shell, jira, jira-rest-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Using the Atlassian documentation, I'm able to create a new JIRA ticket using `curl` command. I want to understand how to read the response of this command into a variable? Essentially i want to store the JIRA ticket ID into a variable that can be used in other scripts.

Reference Link: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

_SAMPLE_CODE_

```
curl -D- -u charlie:charlie -X POST --data '{
    "fields": {
               "project":{
                  "key": "TEST"
               },
               "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
               "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
               "issuetype": {
                  "name": "Bug"
               }
            }
    }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/
```

_SAMPLE_RESPONSE_

```
{
    "id":"39000",
    "key":"TEST-101",
    "self":"http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/39000"
}
```

From the above log, I want to understand how can we fetch the "key" (i.e. JIRA number or JIRA ID) from response (essentially stdout) into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jq command line tool to extract value from json:

```
#!/bin/bash


key=$(curl -s -u charlie:charlie -X POST --data '{
"fields": {
           "project":{
              "key": "TEST"
           },
           "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
           "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
           "issuetype": {
              "name": "Bug"
           }
        }
}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/|jq -r .key)

echo "key: $key"
```

jq command is not installed by default on linux systems.
you will need to install it manually:

```
sudo apt install jq
sudo yum install jq
```

Comment: Hi @Maxim, You mean i should put the entire code under "your parameters here" thing ?

Comment: i tried it, getting following error: `(23) Failed writing body`

Comment: please ensure that jq is installed on your system.

Comment: I got jq installed on the server. There is not error message now, still not getting the JIRA key. Output of the script is: `key:`

Comment: then Jira does not complete request properly and returns json which does not contain key. Did you set proper credentials? You can split that line into independent parts and check each stage.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Working command is `key=$(jq -r '.key' file)`